# Google fonts no longer supports downloaded files?

Tags: css, truetype, google-fonts

I have downloaded .ttf files from google fonts to my local css folder, but can't seem to load them properly. I have tried these approaches:

CSS

```
@import url('./css/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:400,500,600,700');

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Cabin Condensed') format('truetype');
}

body, html {
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

HTML

```
<link href="./css/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't get any errors, but the font is not displayed either.
Strangely, the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) don't even mention local fonts.

Comment: No errors in the console either? Can you verify if they are properly loaded in F12 -> Network tab in your browser?

Comment: `local` will try to load fonts from the system's font-dictionnary. If you haven't installed this font in your system's font dictionnary, the browser won't be able to retrieve it from the `local` function. You'd need to add both `local()` and `url(path/to/local/file)` in your `src` declaration.

Comment: @Kaiido I agree. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me the problem is using the `local` path which requires the font to be installed locally.

Try dropping the  `@import` and add a fallback of `src: url` to your `src: local`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed';
    src: local('Cabin Condensed'), url(<path to the TTF file>);
}
```

e.g:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed';
    src: local('Cabin Condensed'), url('/css/fonts/Cabin-Condensed.ttf');
}
```